# Altering database tables on updating website

Tags: database, updating, alter

This seems to be an issue that keeps coming back in every web application; you're improving the back-end code and need to alter a table in the database in order to do so. No problem doing manually on the development system, but when you deploy your updated code to production servers, they'll need to automatically alter the database tables too.

I've seen a variety of ways to handle these situations, all come with their benefits and own problems. Roughly, I've come to the following two possibilities;

1. Dedicated update script. Requires manually initiating the update. Requires all table alterations to be done in a predefined order (rigid release planning, no easy quick fixes on the database). Typically requires maintaining a separate updating process and some way to record and manage version numbers. Benefit is that it doesn't impact running code.
2. Checking table properties at runtime and altering them if needed. No manual interaction required and table alters may happen in any order (so a quick fix on the database is easy to deploy). Another benefit is that the code is typically a lot easier to maintain. Obvious problem is that it requires checking table properties a lot more than it needs to.

Are there any other general possibilities or ways of dealing with altering database tables upon application updates?

Comment: This is a fairly open ended question. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem is that I'm currently implementing a new web application without an updating system and would like to have some input on what is the best way to handle database updates. It's PHP/MySQL-based, but that shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

I'll share what I've seen work best.  It's just expanding upon your first option.

The steps I've usually seen when updating schemas in production:

1. Take down the front end applications. This prevents any data from being written during a schema update. We don't want writes to fail because relationships are messed up or a table is suddenly out of sync with the application.
2. Potentially disconnect the database so no connections can be made. Sometimes there is code out there using your database you don't even know about!
3. Run the scripts as you described in your first option. It definitely takes careful planning. You're right that you need a pre-defined order to apply the changes. Also I would note often times you need two sets of scripts, one for schema updates and one for data updates. As an example, if you want to add a field that is not nullable, you might add a nullable field first, and then run a script to put in a default value.
4. Have rollback scripts on hand. This is crucial because you might make all the changes you think you need (since it all worked great in development) and then discover the application doesn't work before you bring it back online. It's good to have an exit strategy so you aren't in that horrible place of "oh crap, we broke the application and we've been offline for hours and hours and what do we do?!"
5. Make sure you have backups ready to go in case (4) goes *really* bad.
6. Coordinate the application update with the database updates. Usually you do the database updates first and then roll out the new code.
7. (Optional) A lot of companies do partial roll outs to test.  I've never done this, but if you have 5 application servers and 5 database servers, you can first roll out to 1 application/1 database server and see how it goes. Then if it's good you continue with the rest of the production machines.

It definitely takes time to find out what works best for you. From my experience doing lots of production database updates, there is no silver bullet. The most important thing is taking your time and being disciplined in tracking changes (versioning like you mentioned).